# Invalid pipe argument '' for AsynPipe and this._strategy is null

Tags: angular

So , I created an Article module (with service,componenet etc).

But I am getting a `Invalid pipe argument '' for AsynPipe` error

As data samples, I use a json file that seems well written (no error seems to be with it).

You can find my project on github : https://github.com/kme-rennes/dev-site-as-with-angular/tree/master/src/app

The code seems good to me, and found some examples that look alike. I dind't find any clue about what means the message, since it's empty between the single quotes.

I did group `(articles | async)` because I am anticipating the fact that I will maybe, be counting the items in the ngFor later.

And if I use without (), I got a `this._strategy is null`. And I cannot find any infos on it either.

Here is the code that is concerned (if I forgot some, the full code is on the github) :

html component

```
<p>
  liste-article works!
</p>
<h2 highlight="gold">My articles</h2>

<ul class="articles">
  <li *ngFor="let article of (articles | async)"
      [class.selected]="article === selectedArticle"
      (click)="onSelect(article)">


    <span class="badge">{{article.id}}</span> {{article.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<ngb-pagination (pageChange)="onPager($event)" [pageSize]="itemPerPage" [collectionSize]="totalItems" [(page)]="page" [maxSize]="5" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Article} from '../../model/article';
import {  ArticleService} from '../../model/article.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-liste-article',
  templateUrl: './liste-article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./liste-article.component.css']
})
export class ListeArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  articles: Article[] = [];
  selectedArticle: Article;
  newArticle: Article;
  page = 1;
  itemPerPage = 5;
  totalItems = 120;

  constructor(private router: Router, private articleService: ArticleService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.getArticles().then(articles => this.articles = articles);
  }
  onSelect(article: Article) {
    this.selectedArticle = article;
    this.router.navigate(['../articles', this.selectedArticle.id ]);
  }
  onPager(event: number): void {
    console.log('Page event is' , event);
    this.page = event;

    //this.articleService.getArticles().then(articles => this.articles = articles);

  }

  getArticles(): void {
    this.articleService.getArticles().then(articles => this.articles = articles);
  }
  createArticle(article: Article): void {

    this.articleService.createArticle(article)
      .then(articles => {
        this.articles.push(articles);
        this.selectedArticle = null;
      });
  }

  deleteArticle(article: Article): void {
    this.articleService
      .deleteArticle(article)
      .then(() => {
        this.articles = this.articles.filter(b => b !== article);
        if (this.selectedArticle === article) { this.selectedArticle = null; }
      });
  }
}
```

The service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Article} from './article';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {

  results: Article[];
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private articlesUrl = './assets/articles.json';

  getArticles(): Promise<Article[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.articlesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Article[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  getArticle(id: number): Promise<Article> {
    const url = `${this.articlesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Article)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  createArticle(article: Article): Promise<Article> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.articlesUrl, JSON.stringify(article), { headers: this.headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data as Article)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  updateArticle(article: Article): Promise<Article> {
    const url = `${this.articlesUrl}/${article.id}`;
    return this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(article), { headers: this.headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => article)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  deleteArticle(article: Article): Promise<void> {
    const url = `${this.articlesUrl}/${article.id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, { headers: this.headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

json file

```
 [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name":"1",
        "contenu":"test",
        "urlImage":"https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name":"2",
        "contenu":"test",
        "urlImage":"https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png"
      },
      {
      "id": "3",
      "name":"3",
      "contenu":"test",
      "urlImage":"https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png"
    }
    ]
```

Comment: can you add your `json` as well?

Comment: @Thabung done : it's true that I mentionned he looks OK to me (watching how they are built) but maybe there is an error.

Comment: :) Glad to know

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the use of the async pipe
If you want to take advantage of it, you have to use it after a Promise or an Observable, not on actual data that you assume is "async".

Fix it by changing this:

```
articles: Article[] = [];
```

and this:

```
this.articleService.getArticles().then(articles => this.articles = articles);
```

To this:

```
articles: Promise<Article[]>;
```

and this:

```
this.articles = this.articleService.getArticles();
```

**PS:**

I assume you can remove the `()` after you make this change.

Comment: This indeed removes the error. But then, first I got no results (and with no errors, I assume both my service and json are ok so...Angular is hard to debug when you are starting...), and also, can't use push and filter on my others functions, since I get to Promise with my array.

Comment: True, if you're editing your data after getting it from your service I suggest you don't use the `async` pipe at all.

Comment: Just initialize an empty array at first, `onInit` use `.then` as you did earlier and update your original array, mutate it as you like and just bind straight to it without the `async` pipe.

Comment: sorry, but I don't get what you want me to do there. Furthermore, I don't get the explanations.

Comment: I'm saying you don't even need to use the async pipe

Comment: Just removing the async pipe create another error for the ngFor. And and didn't get the others things you waned me to do( as I said, more globally)...

Comment: ngFor only supports binding to iterables suchas array.

Comment: weird, can you post a plunk?